# NestJS TypeOrmModule repository injection seems not working properly

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to inject user repository to UserService, but it seems that typeorm connection is not making. I've googled about this error, but it seems there's not much resource.

Here's an error log

```
[Nest] 18226  - 2021. 11. 30. 오후 7:10:19   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] 
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserRepository (?). 
Please make sure that the argument Connection at index [0] is available 
in the TypeOrmModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If Connection is a provider, is it part of the current TypeOrmModule?
- If Connection is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TypeOrmModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing Connection */ ]
  })
```

Here's codes

user.service.ts

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User) private readonly user: Repository<User>,
  ) {}

  ...
}
```

user.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  providers: [UserService],
  exports: [UserService],
  controllers: [UserController],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      ...
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      ...,
      synchronize: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'prod',
      logging:
        process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'prod' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test',
      entities: [User, Wiki],
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.MONGODB_ROOT),
    UserModule,
    WikiModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Have you installed all dependencies of the typeorm module: `npm install --save @nestjs/typeorm typeorm pg`?

Comment: Yes everything is installed. Its versions are: 8.0.2, 0.2.41, 8.7.1 respectively

Comment: show us all occurrences of `UserRepository`. Looks like you've added it to `providers` array, but you shouldn't be doing that

Comment: UserRepository only occurs at user.service.ts I've posted above. UserService is the only place that UserRepository is injected. And TypeOrmModule.forFeature only used at imports array in nest modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For someone who's struggling with this issue, just try TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync()

```js
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  useFactory: () => ({
    type: 'postgres',
    ...,
    synchronize: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'prod',
    logging:
      process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'prod' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test',
  }),
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Thansk Joseph Hwang

TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
useFactory: () => ({
type: 'postgres',
...,
synchronize: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'prod',
logging:
process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'prod' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test',
}),
})

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this just looks like a poorly formatted copy of joseph's answer which he made almost a year ago...

Answer (score 1):

When you add Entity decorator, it not automatically added to your datasource.

You always should pass list of entities or entities path to dataSource.

Simple solution that working when you have single database connection.

```js
import { getMetadataArgsStorage } from 'typeorm';
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  useFactory: () => ({
  ...databaseOptions,
  entities: getMetadataArgsStorage().tables.map((table) => table.target),
})
```